# How do I make a reference image in Blender show up when rendering the scene?

Tags: 3d-view, image

I am having an issue with rendering a scene in Blender. When not in rendering mode, Blender shows my reference image with ease. But as soon as I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to render the image, my reference image disappears. I need that reference image because in my scene, I am depicting some sentient cubes watching TV, and I need an image for the TV to show. I have searched around Blender for quite some time and have not found a setting. If it is not possible to show reference images during the rendering process, could you please show a way to do it without a reference image? By the way, if it helps, I am using Blender 2.80.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The whole point of reference images are to help while modeling and setting up a scene, they are not intended to be in the final rendered image.

Blender includes an addon called import images as planes, enable this addon and you get an extra import option *File->Import->Images as Planes*. Using this will setup your image as a texture on a plane so that it will show up in the final render.

Comment: Thank you! That helped, I can't believe I missed doing a textured object!!! :)